# GraphQL Apollo: Variable $bool got invalid value "false"; Expected type Boolean; Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: "false"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

My GQL mutation contains the following schema:

```
    $title: String!
    $body: String
    $bool: Boolean!
```

Yet I cannot get it to pass the boolean value in the mutation. I've ensured the variables are correct such that $bool = false. Yet along the lines somewhere it seems as though a string conversion occurs. I am at a loss with this seemingly simple issue.

Comment: There has to be an issue with how you are providing the variable client side. If you check the network request, I'm pretty sure you'll see a `"false"` instead of `false` in the request body. Please show the relevant front end code.

Comment: Yes it is a string in the request. But I have the variable hardcoded (for testing) as a bool value false.

Comment: I fixed it. I actually had .toString() on the mutation variables. Wow. It's been a long night. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and even though I didn't have `.toString()` in my code, I did have template literals on the query variable, which turned the variable to string. Removing the template literals solved the problem.

Comment: Can confirm that this was the issue for me too. I had something like "${providedConsent}" which converted my boolean to a string. I just need to remove the "" and make it ${providedConsent}